# Visual Studio 2008 Team System Upgrade Removes Code Snippets

Tags: visual-studio-2008, code-snippets

I've been using VS 2008 for several months now and received a copy of VSTS 08 from work and installed without any issues. I upgraded VS 08 to VSTS 08 by running the VSTS installer without uninstalling VS 08. A few hours of after the install, I attempted to create a snippet in a VB project (Try Catch: Ctrl+K,Ctrl+X) and nothing happened. On the line where I pressed the shortcuts, the line "Insert Snippet:No Snippets Available" shows up.

In attempt to resolve, I un-installed all the the VS 08 applications, and re-installed using only the VSTS 08. To no avail.

After reading a post somewhere, I removed all the snippets using the Code Snippet Manager and re-added them and still not working.

Any suggestions on how to get them to work properly?

Comment: Do you have the tools for Silverlight 3 installed - in particular patch KB967143? Do you have any other add-ins or packages installed? I've heard of problems when changing Pro `<->` TS editions, but I'm sure it's nothing that can't be figured out. :)

Comment: @Stevoni - the patch I refer to is a silent install during the S3 install - you'll have to check add/remove programs with Show Updates checked.

Comment: @280Z28- I don't have the tools installed and the second time, I uninstalled all the add-ins as well and still had the same problem.

I'll have to check for the patch when I get to work tomorrow.

Comment: @280Z28 - I couldn't find the patch you're talking about and since I don't have Silverlight 3 I'm not that surprised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found came from a [MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/d5307f8d-2c47-45d9-ae96-ee8a44e4b2db) that I just found due to the lack of relevant keywords to VS 2008.

I didn't have to do the registry edit to get it to work again.